# Type inference with interfaces

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, clr

Just the other day I cam across a bug that actually took me a while to figure out.
Somehow it seemed that the wrong overload was executed when executing through an inherited interface. Take a look at this code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IBar bar = new Bar();                   
        bar.Execute("TEST");
    }
}


public interface IFoo
{
    void Execute(string value);
}

public interface IBar : IFoo
{
    void Execute(object value);
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public void Execute(string value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo.Execute - string");
    }
}

public class Bar : IBar
{
    public void Execute(string value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bar.Execute - string");
    }

    public void Execute(object value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bar.Execute - object");
    }
}
```

The output from this program is "Bar-Execute - object" that for me seems a little strange since a more specific overload is available through the inherited IFoo interface. Can anyone explain this behavior?

Best regards

Bernhard Richter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in this blog you can find explanation: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx

> When the compiler goes looking for instance method overloads, it
>   considers the compile-time class of the "target" of the call, and
>   looks at methods declared there. If it can't find anything suitable,
>   it then looks at the parent class... then the grandparent class, etc.
>   This means that if there are two methods at different levels of the
>   hierarchy, the "deeper" one will be chosen first, even if it isn't a
>   "better function member" for the call.